# ActiveMQ replicated levelDB with zookeeper can not visited?

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

I have 3 zookeeper machines and 3 activemq machines.
here is the configuration.
   zookeeper：
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=2
dataDir=/var/zookeeper/data
clientPort=2181
server.153=192.168.62.153:2888:3888
server.156=192.168.62.156:2888:3888
server.158=192.168.62.158:2888:3888
   activemq：

```
<replicatedLevelDB 
    directory="/opt/apache-activemq-5.11.1/data/leveldb"
    replicas="3"
    bind="tcp://0.0.0.0"                                          
    zkAddress="192.168.62.153:2181,192.168.62.156:2181,192.168.62.158:2181"
    hostname="192.168.62.153"
    zkPath="/opt/zookeeper/leveldb-stores"
    sync="local_disk"
/>
```

First, I started the three zookeeper machines, then I started the three activemq machines.
the zookeeper machine showed one leader and two flowers.
But when I view the activemq webconsole http://ip:8161, whatever which activemq machine, it can not be visited. 
There is no error message in the log, but a warning like this:

> SASL configuration failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file: '/opt/apache-activemq-5.11.1/conf/login.config'. Will continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication, if Zookeeper server allows it. | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn
>   | main-SendThread.

Please help me fixed the problem.

Comment: The master has been promoted. But no one to be the slave. So it can not be visited.

Answer (score 0):

This warning mustn't interfere in you communication with zk server. You can read that communication go on

```
"Will continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL"
```

Later in you log you should see these following lines who show that communication goes fine  :

```
2016-05-13 17:16:50,867 | WARN  | unprocessed event state: AuthFailed | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.groups.ZKClient | main-EventThread
2016-05-13 17:16:50,878 | INFO  | Socket connection established to zkserver.stuff.com/192.168.1.xxxx:2181, initiating session | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(server.yourdomain.com:2181)
2016-05-13 17:16:50,894 | INFO  | Session establishment complete on server zkserver.stuff.com/192.168.1.xxxx:2181, sessionid = 0x154aa93a6900001, negotiated timeout = 4000 | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn | main-SendThread(zkserver.stuff.com/192.168.1.xxxx:2181)
```